# On get request why do I get back the blade view, when I should get data from the database instead?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, get, axios

I a have the following **get request**, which is executed on **mounted()**.
In some weird mysterious ways, I get back my main view **app.blade** as a response when I am clearly requesting some data from the **database**.

Can someone spot what I messed up?

My **get request** on the front-end:

```
mounted() {
this.getProjectRequests();
},
methods: {
getProjectRequests: function() {
  var self = this;
  let clientId = this.$route.path.substring(
    this.$route.path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
  );
  axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "/get-project-requests/" + clientId
  })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      // TODO error handling
    });
}
}
```

My **route**:

```
Route::get('/get-project-requests/{client_id}', 
'SinglePageController@getProjectRequests');
```

And my **controller method**:

```
public function getProjectRequests($clientId) {
  try {
         $projectRequests = ProjectRequest::where('client_id', 
         $clientId)->value('name');
         return response()->json( [
                    'success'=> true,
                    'projectRequests' => $projectRequests
                ]);
            } catch(\Exception $e){
                return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'getting 
                project requests failed'];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this `ProjectRequest::where('client_id', $clientId)->value('name');` giving exception.

Either you check your **laravel.log** inside **storage/logs** folder or change that method into

```
    // Not working on eloquent model
    $valueOject = ProjectRequest::where('client_id',$clientId)->value('name');

    // DB facade its working. Change to this method
    $valueOject = DB::table('{your_table}')->where('client_id', $clientId)->value('name');

    dd($valueOject);
```

Comment: It does not throw me an exception, it simply returns the only view I have as a response, as if I was requesting  `return view('app');`